# Redefining hyperref in document referencing

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, amsmath, cleveref

With some help (by google) I was able to come up with a code allowing me to cross-reference enumerated items in `amsthm`-type enviroments via hyperref. The links and code work, but the `hyperref` link takes me directly to the referenced item (as intended by `hyperref`).

What I want to achieve is for hyperref to bring the screen to the Lemma itself and not to item (i), as the Lemma most of the time has a description which is important for all the items.

To see this interaction I was forced to put in some spacing. So sorry for the bunch of blindtext.

You might now ask why the trouble with `cleveref` at all. Because I will need to relabel Lemmas into Propositions or theorems or add in more items during my work process and I want the references to update automatically.

Thank you in advance.

Best regards 
Bob

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{amsart}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \usepackage{nameref,hyperref}
    \hyperbaseurl{.}
    \usepackage[capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}
    \usepackage{enumitem}

    \usepackage{amsmath,amscd,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
    \usepackage{thmtools}   

    \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
    \newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}    


    \newlist{lemlist}{enumerate}{1}
    \setlist[lemlist]{label=(\roman{lemlisti}), 
                      ref=\thetheorem.(\roman{lemlisti}),
                      noitemsep}

    \Crefname{lemma}{Lemma}{Lemmas}
    \addtotheorempostheadhook[lemma]{\crefalias{lemlisti}{lemma}}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[2]

\begin{lemma} 
Some important description for something and something else
\begin{lemlist}
  \item \label{1} something
  \item \label{2} something else
\end{lemlist} 
\end{lemma}

\blindtext[2]

\cref{1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 3):

You need two labels for this, one for the number and one for the destination. You can then use `\hyperref` to setup the link.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{amsart}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \usepackage{nameref,hyperref}
    \hyperbaseurl{.}
    \usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
    \usepackage{enumitem}

    \usepackage{amsmath,amscd,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
    \usepackage{thmtools}

    \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
    \newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}


    \newlist{lemlist}{enumerate}{1}
    \setlist[lemlist]{label=(\roman{lemlisti}), ref=\thetheorem.(\roman{lemlisti}),noitemsep}

    \Crefname{lemma}{Lemma}{Lemmas}
    \addtotheorempostheadhook[lemma]{\crefalias{lemlisti}{lemma}}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[2]


\begin{lemma}\label{main}
some important discription for something and something else
\begin{lemlist}
\item \label{1} something
\item \label{2} something else
\end{lemlist}
\end{lemma}
\blindtext[2]
\cref{1}

\hyperref[main]{\cref*{1}} or \namecref{1}~\hyperref[main]{\ref*{1}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The examples given by you work well, but do not give what I had in mind. I would prefer to find a somewhat "global approch". I should have stated that in my question.

Comment: well a global approach would need that you know the "parent" counter of your item (with some declaration/definition), that you store its value/destination name along with the label (possible e.g. with zref) and that you then make everything compatible with hyperref and cref (possible but not done in a few minutes).

Comment: zref seems to provide what is needed to acces the needed information. I do not have enough time at the moment to build an implementation. But in about two month I might try to build it that way.